# How to rename a file in ftp server using java

Tags: java, ftp

I wanted  know

How to rename a file in ftp server using java.

I am using `java.net.URL` to connect to the server

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Apaches FTPClient. Its much easier

http://commons.apache.org/net/

```
FTPClient.rename(String from, String to);
```

Comment: Just to note this. If You are using windows machine as a FTP client, do not create FTP shared folder directly on C:\{some_folder} because of windows(windows 8) security restriction.

Answer (score 5):

In the name of all that's holy, don't try and write your own FTP client.

Use [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/), it comes with an [FTP client class](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) for you to use.

Comment: Even if your answer is right and must be underlined, the answer of Tommy is more helpful in my opinion.

Comment: Well the quesrion wasn't how to rename using FTPClient, it was how to rename using java.net.URL, but fair enough.